# Fruit Oil Extraction

Tags: oil, fat, nutrient-composition

I'm making an experiment which compares different oils.  It seems I can make oil from any fruit/seed
by just pressing it, filtering the liquid outflow, and letting the filtered liquid settle (keeping only
the liquid which settles above the water in the end).

Though not refined, I should be able to thereby make olive oil and sunflower oil for starters.

Then, it seems I should be able to make grape oil or grapefruit oil with the exact same procedure.
But, I can't find nutrition facts about these two oils on the internet, so I'm wondering if no oil
would be produced, or if this is really considered juice (but that doesn't make sense because juice
normally includes water; even "concentrated juice" doesn't seem right since it isn't slippery like
normal oil).  Anyway, what happens when you use the exact same procedure on sweet fruits like this?
If you truly make oil, what is the saturated fat content for extraction from a grape or a grapefruit?

Ultimately, I want to compare the saturated fat content of many fruit oils, extracted by a universal
method, so a big table here would be the best answer.  But, I don't even know if this is possible
since people don't even talk about the oils from normal fruits.

Comment: Grapeseed oil is quite widely used, so you might be able to reproduce that. I don't have a clue if the seeds of a grapefruit are oily enough for your purposes though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For grapes you don't make oil from the fruit, you [make it from the seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grape_seed_oil). The only entries in [this table](http://www.containerhandbuch.de/chb_e/scha/scha_17_03.html) for fruit "flesh" are for [oil palm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elaeis_guineensis) and [olives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olive).

Assuming the price of some oils correspond to the difficultly to get a reasonable yield,
I think their will not be enough oil in grapefruit (or grape flesh) to extract, otherwise it would probably have been done so commercially already.

Comment: Since a tiny amount of oil seems extractable from grape flesh, I wonder if that oil would have the same saturated fat content as the oil from the grape seed...  In my experiment, I'm now thinking to do both seed and flesh extraction (for many fruits), measuring both oil output and saturated fat output (per kg).  I would guess some of this has been measured by someone before, so waiting a little before I mark you as the answer.  From your answer, it sounds like I will need a lot of grape flesh (50 kg?) to reliably get oil!

Comment: I realized that I can just use the published nutrition fat content of grapes:  Per 50 kg of grapes (or grape juice), I should get about 50 g of oil, of which 20 g is saturated fat.  Grape skin alone might be the same factor, and I'm simply including it as "flesh".  Anyway, it's interesting that grape fat is therefore 40% saturated, but grape seed oil fat is separately published as being only 10% saturated.  I'm simply thinking that grape seed is different from, and healthier than, grape skin.

Comment: They are bound to be different, it is not as if the fat is produced in the seeds and a portion is "leaked" to the flesh. I would be conservative on what you can actually get out of 50kg with the non-optimal extraction conditions you described. OTOH I don't know how much you need for actual saturation factor testing.